# CORS Error with Microsoft MSAL-Node request

Tags: oauth-2.0, cors, azure-ad-msal, msal-react

I am receiving a CORS error when I am attempting to receive an auth token through a client credential request using msal-node. I can get the token through a request with Postman but when I use my React App localhost it gives me a CORS error.

Do I have to allow request from a local host in Azure? Code is below.

Helpful links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/no4sv.png)

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddJc0.png)

I tried to get a token using a client credential request and got a cors error.

Answer (score 0):

Client credentials are not intended to be used from a browser. [CORS is supported only in SPA enabled app registrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#redirect-uris-for-single-page-apps-spas). You need to switch to a non browser environment.